# Cumulative sum of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

So i'm working on a problem that focuses on taking the cumulative sum of an array so for example if i have an array of ({0,2,3,-1,-1}) it returns {0,2,5,4,3}... or if you have an array of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] it should return [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]...

Right now i'm struggling with two problems one i have to use the method given and i'm struggling with what to return because total will not.. To my code i know it works for adding up the sum of an array but not the cumulative sum as in my examples.. any guidelines would be helpful.

```
public int[] makeCumul(int[] in) {
    int[] out = { in.length };
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
        total += out[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: You're never reading any of the elements of `in`.  That seems problematic.

Comment: This won't even compile.  You say you're going to return an `int[]` but you're returning an `int`.

Comment: sorry i do i call it in my main method with a set up array..

Comment: Your code has several basic errors in it. 1) You are creating `out` as a size 1 array.  2) Your method sig says you return an `int[]` but you're actually returning an int. 3) You never actually read any of the values in the input array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not reading the in array, partly, but also not updating the out array, and not returning it. This should work for you.

```
public int[] makeCumul(int[] in) {
    int[] out = new int[in.length];
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        total += in[i];
        out[i] = total;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int in[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int[] out = new int[in.length];
        out[0] = in[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < out.length; i++) 
            out[i] = out[i-1] + in[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) 
            System.out.print(out[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45
```

If you want to put this in a method, you can return the last element like this:

```
return out[out.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] makeCumul(int[] in) {
    int[] out = new int[in.length];
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++){
        sum += in[i];
        out[i] = sum;
    }
    return out;
}
```

I believe this is what you are looking for. Keep a cumulative sum, and update that sum with each element. After you update the sum, replace the element with the sum.

When you create a new array, to initialize it use

```
int[] out = new int[ARRAY SIZE HERE];
```

You should also note that in the method signature you are returning an array of integers, and the variable `total` is an integer, not an array of integers. So you want to return the variable `out`.

Gives me the output:

```
0
2
5
4
3
```