# Java Increment issues

Tags: java, sum, syntax-error

Within my while loop below I get an syntax error under "+=".  I went here but the answer didn't help me.
[Cumulative sum of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335660/cumulative-sum-of-an-array)

I am just trying to print each cumulative sum that is being streamed from the server.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {
        //Create client socket, connect to server
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",9999);
        //create output stream attached to socket
        PrintStream outToServer = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        System.out.print("Command : ");
        //create input stream
        InputStreamReader inFromUser = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader ed = new BufferedReader(inFromUser);

        String temp = ed.readLine();

        outToServer.println(temp);
        //create input stream attached to socket
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String display=null;
        while((display = inFromServer.readLine())!=null){
        int displayByt = Integer.valueOf(display);
        double totalByt += displayByt;//SYNTAX ERROR  "+="
          //totalByt = totalByt + displayByt; Does not Work either
        System.out.print(totalByt);
        System.out.print("\n");
        }
        clientSocket.close();
    }
```

Comment: `double totalByt += displayByt;` makes no sense because `double totalByt = double totalByt + displayByt;` makes no sense.

Comment: `totalByt` needs an initial value?

Comment: @justin Thank you

Comment: @n00bie1221 I see several folks answered while I was typing the full response. But you have some examples now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define and initialize `totalByt` before the loop, and only add to it in the loop, not attempt to redefine it:

```
double totalByt = 0.0; // Defined and initialized here
while ((display = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
    int displayByt = Integer.valueOf(display);
    totalByt += displayByt; // Used here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i always forget

Answer (score 0):

Move the **declaration** and **initialization** of `totalByt` before your loop. Increment it in the loop. And display with `System.out.println` instead of two calls to `print`. Like,

```
double totalByt = 0; // <-- declare and set to 0.
while((display = inFromServer.readLine())!=null){
    int displayByt = Integer.valueOf(display);
    totalByt += displayByt;
    System.out.println(totalByt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple

Answer (score 0):

I think the only issue here is that your `totalByt` variable needs an initial value. Basically the way your code is written, you are trying to add an integer to nothing.

Try this:

```
String display=null;
double totalByt = 0;
while((display = inFromServer.readLine())!=null){

    int displayByt = Integer.valueOf(display);
    totalByt += displayByt;

    System.out.print(totalByt);
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize totalByt.  That should fix the problem.